# Social Engine 4 main log how to repair errors?

Tags: plugins, socialengine

I dont understand this error code, can somebody explain this log? I will try to repair errors, but i need little help.

```
2014-02-22T12:44:46+00:00 WARN (4): [2048] Declaration of Wall_Model_DbTable_Actions::getActivity() should be compatible with Activity_Model_DbTable_Actions::getActivity(User_Model_User $user, array $params = Array) (/home/socpt613/public_html/application/modules/Wall/Model/DbTable/Actions.php) [22]
Error Code: 856062
Stack trace:
#0 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Loader.php(103): include_once('/home/socpt613/public_html/appli...')
#1 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Loader.php(130): Engine_Loader::autoload('Wall_Model_DbTable_Actions')
#2 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Loader.php(160): Engine_Loader::loadClass('Wall_Model_DbTable_Actions')
#3 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Api.php(268): Engine_Loader->load('Wall_Model_DbTable_Actions')
#4 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Api.php(241): Engine_Api->load('wall', 'dbtable', 'actions')
#5 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/modules/Wall/widgets/feed/Controller.php(196): Engine_Api->__call('getDbtable', Array)
#6 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/modules/Wall/widgets/feed/Controller.php(196): Engine_Api->getDbtable('actions', 'wall')
#7 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Widget/Abstract.php(254): Wall_Widget_FeedController->indexAction()
#8 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Element/Widget.php(73): Engine_Content_Widget_Abstract->render()
#9 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Element/Abstract.php(583): Engine_Content_Element_Widget->_render()
#10 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Decorator/Children.php(31): Engine_Content_Element_Abstract->render()
#11 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Element/Abstract.php(594): Engine_Content_Decorator_Children->render('')
#12 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Decorator/Children.php(31): Engine_Content_Element_Abstract->render()
#13 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Element/Abstract.php(594): Engine_Content_Decorator_Children->render('')
#14 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Decorator/Children.php(31): Engine_Content_Element_Abstract->render()
#15 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Element/Abstract.php(594): Engine_Content_Decorator_Children->render('')
#16 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Content.php(208): Engine_Content_Element_Abstract->render()
#17 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Controller/Action/Helper/Content.php(136): Engine_Content->render('user_index_home')
#18 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Content/Controller/Action/Helper/Content.php(38): Engine_Content_Controller_Action_Helper_Content->render()
#19 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php(277): Engine_Content_Controller_Action_Helper_Content->postDispatch()
#20 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action.php(523): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->notifyPostDispatch()
#21 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(289): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('homeAction')
#22 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Front.php(946): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Http, Zend_Controller_Response_Http)
#23 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/modules/Core/Bootstrap.php(75): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#24 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Application.php(160): Core_Bootstrap->run()
#25 /home/socpt613/public_html/application/index.php(205): Engine_Application->run()
#26 /home/socpt613/public_html/index.php(24): include('/home/socpt613/public_html/appli...')
#27 {main}
```

I have more errors but I need explain only one.
I have a licenced SE4.7 with plugins and licenced HIRE-Expert plugins but If I install HIRE EXPERT plugins, my log have realy more errors. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error occurs in module Wall, in controller of widget Feed. There are problems in capability of getting activity feed items between standard Activity's model and custom model (Wall_Model_DbTable_Actions / Activity_Model_DbTable_Actions).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a compatible issue. 
You can compare the declration of these methods and you will see the difference:

```
Wall_Model_DbTable_Actions::getActivity(User_Model_User $user, $params = array())

Activity_Model_DbTable_Actions::getActivity(User_Model_User $user, array $params = Array)
```

Add array before the second parameter and it will solve this warning error.

Hope this help you.